# stuck in trying to use uiee in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not new to programming but new to mssql.  I have searched online for help with this but am     getting nowhere.

I have a book inventory file in UIEE format.

```
UR|2706
AA|Parker, William Harwar
TI|RECOLLECTIONS OF A NAVAL OFFICER, 1841-1865:
XD|S
UR|15184
AA|Goodrich, Norma Lorre
TI|King Arthur
```

and so on.  As you see each line is tagged and each record starts with a 'UR' tag and ends with a 'XD' tag.  I've uploaded this to a mssql table called testuiee with columns tag and data.  I'm trying to use sql to identify the fields and put them into another table called btdata.  For example, put UR data into Book id, AA into author, etc.

```
Book_id   Author                   Title
2706      Parker, William Harwar   RECOLLECTIONS OF A NAVAL OFFICER, 1841-1865:
15184     Goodrich, Norma Lorre    King Arthur
```

The script I wrote works but only puts the last record into the btdata table.  I've tried conditional processing, (while, if, case) and also a cursor but the result is always one record, the last one. King Arthur in this example.  I'm sure its because I am thinking of things in a row by row way and not in blocks of data but I can't get my head around this.

Here's my code so far.

```
DECLARE @bookid nvarchar(max),
        @author nvarchar(max),
        @title nvarchar(max)


SELECT tag, data from testuiee


SELECT @bookid = data from testuiee where tag = 'UR' 
SELECT @author = data from testuiee where tag = 'AA'
SELECT @title = data from testuiee where tag = 'TI'


IF @bookid IS NOT NULL
INSERT INTO btdata (book_id, author, title) 
VALUES (@bookid, @author, @title)


GO
```

I did try to use the 'XD' tag conditionally to execute the insert but the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a row number field or similar to order by in the `testuiee` table? Remember that rows in the database are unordered, even if they often appear to stay in insertion order.

Comment: I did not.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an Auto ID field/Rownumber field in your table to be able to keep the Rows together.
With you script you will get "random" values fitting your condition.
Using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by tag Order By ID)` you are able to join your CTE with 3 aliases for the desired result.

Using SQL Server 2008 + you might use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
declare  @testui Table (ID integer Identity(1,1),tag varchar(10),data varchar(50))
declare @dest Table (book_id varchar(50),author varchar(50),title varchar(50)) 

Insert into @Testui
Select 'UR','2706'
Insert into @Testui
Select 'AA','Parker, William Harwar'
Insert into @Testui
Select 'TI','RECOLLECTIONS OF A NAVAL OFFICER, 1841-1865:'
Insert into @Testui
Select 'XD','S'
Insert into @Testui
Select 'UR','15184'
Insert into @Testui
Select 'AA','Goodrich, Norma Lorre'
Insert into @Testui
Select 'TI','King Arthur'

;With CTE as (
Select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by tag Order By ID) as RN
from @Testui)
Insert into @dest
Select a1.Data as book_id,a2.data author,a3.data title 
from CTE a1 
JOIN CTE a2 ON a1.RN=A2.RN
JOIN CTE a3 ON a1.RN=A3.RN
Where a1.tag='UR' and a2.tag='AA' and a3.tag='TI' 

Select * from @dest
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I was thinking that I needed some kind of array.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @new2sql gratifying that I could help